# Using stringWithFormat for query setup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, stringwithformat

Not entirely sure why this isn't working.

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db);
NSString *query;

NSNumber *start = (*cur_page * 50) - 50;

query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT rest_db.rest_id, rest_db.name, prices.value FROM rest_db JOIN prices ON rest_db.rest_id = prices.table_id WHERE prices.table_name = 'rest_db'  ORDER BY rest_db.name ASC %d Limit 50;", start];
```

Previously, the code looked like:

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db);
NSString *query;

query = @"SELECT rest_db.rest_id, rest_db.name, prices.value FROM rest_db JOIN prices ON rest_db.rest_id = prices.table_id WHERE prices.table_name = 'rest_db'  ORDER BY rest_db.name ASC";
```

which worked just fine.  I've tried setting start as:

```
int start
int *start
NSString *start
```

and of course I changed the "%d" accordingly for the string.  All to no avail.  I'm clueless at the moment.  The program crashes when I hit this page now.  No errors, can't get anything to write using NSLog.

I've also tried using:

```
[NSString alloc] initWithFormat
```

Any ideas?  They are appreciated.  Thanks.

> ----------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------

```
.h

int page_count;
int cur_page;

@property int page_count;
@property int cur_page;


.m

@synthesize page_count;
@synthesize cur_page;

int start = (cur_page * 50) - 50;

query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT rest_db.rest_id, rest_db.name, prices.value FROM rest_db JOIN prices ON rest_db.rest_id = prices.table_id WHERE prices.table_name = 'rest_db'  ORDER BY rest_db.name ASC %d Limit 50;", start];
```

And now, since I did fix a typecast thanks to one of the previous suggestions, it doesn't crash the program, but shows no data from the query as start = 0.  Which as I look over my code is exactly what it should equal, and if I had my sqlite statement set up correctly, I would see that I am putting it into the limit in the wrong place... -.-  So the initial typecast issue was the crash and only issue, it would seem.

Comment: Also observe that your [SQLite syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) is wrong -- the start value should be specified as "limit x,50", or as "limit 50 offset x".

Comment: Right, that's what I mentioned when I wrote that edit. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `NSNumber *start = (*cur_page * 50) - 50;` is calculating an integer value and then assigning that int value to the pointer `start`, producing an invalid pointer.  `start` should be declared as an `int` or `NSInteger`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I had originally tried declaring it as an int to no avail.  I also just tried NSInteger with the same issue.

Comment: It may be because `cur_page` (whose declaration you do not disclose) is an NSNumber.  If that's the case you should say `[cur_page intValue]` instead of `*cur_page`.

Comment: The declaration is changed to suit whatever I declare start as.  So when start was an int, cur_page was originally declared as an int.  Same when it was an NSInteger or NSNumber.

Comment: If everything was declared as an int (and without the `*`) then it would have worked with `%d`.  But I'm guessing you have essentially zero experience with C code, so you don't quite understand the significance of the `*`.

Comment: Close to 0 experience, but I know that the * represents a pointer to the object and not the actual object, correct?  But I've tried with and without the * while attempting this.  I will post my current declarations and code in my original post in just a moment.

Comment: There was no apparent need to deal with NSNumbers in the code you've shown us, so I'm wondering where you even got the idea.

Comment: Because I was trying several different type casts to see what would work.  But the initial issue was that the 2 variables had different type casts when I first wrote it.  The cur_page was an int, and the start I had as an NSNumber for whatever reason.  But when I fixed that, I still had an issue.  Thinking it was the same issue, I continued to seek ideas until I seen my sqlite statement error.

Comment: Until you get it working the way you like, NSLog all of your SQLite source statements, so you can see what you're generating.

Answer (score 0):

Try using %@ instead of %d.  %d is for integers; NSNumber is an objective-c object.

Also, instead of

```
NSNumber *start = (*cur_page * 50) - 50;
```

try

```
NSNumber *start = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([cur_page intValue] * 50) - 50];
```

Assuming cur_page is of type NSNumber*.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Or, better, change `start` to an `int` or `NSInteger` (without the `*`).  Or, if he insists on using the NSNumber, code `[start intValue]`, (though I'm skeptical whether that assignment to `start` is producing the right result in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this results in the same issue.  Though my cur_page was originally of the type int, I have changed it accordingly for these trials.  I have also tried the NSInteger to no avail as well.

Comment: Show us the declaration for cur_page, and how you set its value.